# problems Integrating an asp.net website into an asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, simplemembership

I am creating a asp.net mvc 4 application to replace a suite of existing projects
including an asp.net 3.5 website and windows forms.

I have spent many months developing the asp.net mvc 4 application from scratch and
I have been focusing on the windows forms appliction.

I am now trying to integrate the asp.net 3.5 website....For now I am just trying 
to add the website to the project.  I have looked for how to do this and I see
most of what I need...but I have a few problems.

I am using areas.  For the Carrier area (where the website applies) I have added
a folder called aspnet...and I have added the webpages and the other code to this
folder....All of this compiles.

I have also modified the RoutConfig.Cs file by adding this line:
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

When I added the webpages to the project I added just the code, ignoring the 
project files and the web.config for the asp.net website.....

I don't think I need to convert over the project files at all...but I am 
trying to figure out what to do with the web.config....I know I can have
a web.config in the aspnet folder....but what to put into is my question.....

I tried just copying the existing file, but it had issues with the different
.net version (website is v3.5 and the mvc application is v4.0 of .net)....

My big concern is how to handle the security...the website used forms authentication security
and the mvc application uses simpleMembership.

All of the reading I have done focused on converting asp.net web applications,
not websites over to mvc.....and most don't say much about the web.config
file....

Nor have I found what to do with the security...again I have seen some things
on integrating the security model of MVC back into an existing asp.net web application,
but nothing on how to get an asp.net website working with the mvc simplemembership.

help!!

Comment: Please Mention What is your exact Problem ? what you tried ? Post Some Code

Comment: My problem is figuring out what has to be modified to get an asp.net website working within an asp.net mvc application.... I think it is just the web.config ..... I am working on this now .... trying to figure out what has to be added...

Comment: I was very confused....I was looking for some general guidelines about how to install an asp.net website into an existing asp.net mvc application as I could not find anything about this....turns out my problem was not asp.net .... but a devexpress control....I still have not solved the problem, but now I know enough to work on the solution....thanks to all who took the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Both Web Forms and MVC use forms authentication for security. What differs is the membership/roles providers used.  Web forms traditionally used the default ASP.NET providers, whereas MVC now uses the SimpleMembership providers.  Here are the setting in the web.config for configuring the SimpleMembership providers.

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
</system.web>
```

Notice that you configure forms authentication the same way as web forms. The main difference is setting the role and membership provider to [SimpleRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) respectively.  You will need to include the assembly WebMatrix.WebData in your references.  SimpleMembership uses EF code first so initialization of the database at app start up is crucial. Read this article on [seeding and customizing SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html) which will give you some tips on how you might want to tackle database initialization in your app.  There is an open source project called [SimpleSecurity](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) that decouples SimpleMembership from the application, which will make it easier to incorporate into your project and provides a simple method call to initialize it.  You can [read more about it here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html).